# visual studio 2022 and older versions support

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have visual studio plugin which was working in 32 bit visual studio that is 2019 and older version.
Now i want support visual studio 2022 64 bit. For this is i need to have two vsix like one for 2019 and older version and one for 2022 version. Or with a single vsix can we target 2022 and older versions.

I am following visual studio documentataion, as it mentioned there i created shared project and two vsix projects are there one to target 2019 and older version and one to target for 2022 version. I have doubt like if we have two vsix projects is it possible to build one vsix or both vsix projects will generate two dll separately. Any suggestion how it will be build having two vsix project and shared project if we build solution.

Comment: Not sure why it would be any different to any other solution. You build the solution and it builds all projects. Loads of solutions generate multiple DLLs and/or EXEs.

Comment: Meansour plugin to support visualstuido 2022 (64bit) and visual studio 2019(and older version(32bit) ,using single vsix can we target both version or we need two seperate vsix two target both version.

Comment: I think you need two seperate vsix two target both version

Comment: @ThejasJainMj You can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of this official document:

[Update a Visual Studio extension for Visual Studio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022)

> The advice in this article can guide developers in migrating
> extensions that require major changes to work in both Visual Studio
> 2019 and Visual Studio 2022. In those cases, we recommend that you
> have two VSIX projects and conditional compilation.

So you need two seperate vsix, precisely, two seperate extension projects.